# Type uint256 not decrementing in a struct data type

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a basic struct:

```
struct Test {
  uint256 rank;
}
```

Stored in a mapping:

```
mapping(bytes32 => Test) store;
```

I am trying to decrement the 'rank' of a specific Test from the mapping:

```
Test storage test = store[key];
test.rank--;
```

The rank of the corresponding struct in the mapping doesnt change and I cannot figure out why.

I also tried:

```
Test memory test = store[key];
test.rank--;
store[key] = test;
```

But none seem to work. Any hint is much appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: uint256 cannot be a negative number. Are you setting the rank to something > 0 before decrementing? That's my first thought when looking at your code.

Comment: Yes the initial value is set to 10.

Comment: Both of the variants you tried work fine for me. As does the more straightforward `store[key].rank--;`. Could you share how you're testing this? Are you sure you're making a transaction and that the transaction is succeeding?

Answer (score 1):

That was simple:

```
struct Test {
    uint256 rank;
}
mapping(bytes32 => Test) public store;

function setStore(uint256 _unt) returns(bytes32){
    bytes32 aux = sha3("i");
    store[aux].rank = _unt;
    return aux;
}
function minusYolo(bytes32 _key) returns(uint256){
    store[_key].rank--;
    return store[_key].rank;

}
```

Hope it helps